# Administrative Password doesn't work after it changed by GUI

Tags: 14.04, password, password-recovery

I am new to Linux. I have changed my administrative password by GUI (under user accounts setting). But Now its not accepting my password. It says wrong password try again.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my dell vostro 2520, single boot ubuntu.

I am also unable to access recovery mode by pressing and holding shift key.

Thanks in advance. Waiting for solution for this problem.

Comment: Try to access the tty by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1. You should be prompted to log in. Try both your old and your new password. Which one works?

Comment: No its not working with both of my password old and new.
I entered 

maddy login : maddy
password : (my old password)

and again my new password but both not working